# Understanding a statement

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I am writing an SSRS report and I was given a SQL statement to retrieve the data. I am trying to understand the `if` statement below  The SQL statements were not in TSQL so, I converted them first. I am not sure how to convert the `if` condition.

```
select s.name as FullName, s.course, s.fromdate, s.todate,dept.agency
from student as s inner join
department as dept on s.department = dept.departmentid
If lngDeptid <> 0 Then 
strReportSQL = strReportSQL & " AND department.departmentid = " & 
lngDeptid 
End If 
order by s.name
```

Dataset:

```
select s.name as FullName, s.course, s.fromdate, s.todate,dept.agency
from student as s inner join
department as dept on s.department = dept.departmentid
where dept.departmentid  = @dept
order by s.name
```

I am trying to create the report and the drop down menu for `dept id`. Can anyone help me understand the `if` statement and how to add it to my dataset?

Comment: If dropdown isnt working properly then that is a different question.If you want help on how pass a parameter to a query again is a different question. If you want know how handle when a paramenter is optional you have Gordon answer.

Comment: For clarity, you said you want a dropdown menu for `dept id` yet you didn't include the `dept id` in the select statement.  Are you trying to populate the drop down with `dept id` values?  If so, you need to set the parameter's available values to get values from a query and the value and label should be set to that `dept id` you select.  For that scenario, you'd probably be better off creating a new dataset that specifically selects the `dept id` values as it seems the other select statement gets relevant values within the report and references the `dept id` parameter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if` doesn't work like that with SQL statements.  You want logic like this:

```
select s.name as FullName, s.course, s.fromdate, s.todate, d.agency
from student  s inner join
     department d
     on s.department = d.departmentid
where @dept = 0 OR d.departmentid = @dept
order by s.name
```

Comment: I edited the post to add query that I used to create my dataset. however, my drop down menu is not functioning properly. @dept is the drop down parameter I created